# Theano: when was the filter_flip parameter for conv2d introduced? (TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filter_flip')

Tags: python, theano

When was the `filter_flip` parameter for `theano.tensor.nnet.conv2d()` introduced in Theano? (i.e., which is the minimum Theano version that supports it?)

My version (`0.7.0.dev-8d3a67b73fda49350d9944c9a24fc9660131861c`) doesn't have it:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/nnet/conv.py", line 146, in conv2d
    imshp=imshp, kshp=kshp, nkern=nkern, bsize=bsize, **kargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filter_flip'
```

[Theano's change log](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/NEWS.html) doesn't mention `filter_flip`. The [documentation for `theano.tensor.nnet.conv2d()`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nnet/conv.html#theano.tensor.nnet.conv2d) doesn't mention the minimum required version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears in [version 0.8.0](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/rel-0.8.0/theano/tensor/nnet/__init__.py#L35).

Note that in that release the implementation of `theano.tensor.nnet.conv2d()` found in `theano/tensor/nnet/conv.py` [becomes deprecated](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/rel-0.8.0/theano/tensor/nnet/conv.py#L43) and is replaced by the new implementation placed into [`theano/tensor/nnet/__init__.py`](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/rel-0.8.0/theano/tensor/nnet/__init__.py#L35) and [`theano/tensor/nnet/abstract_conv.py`](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/rel-0.8.0/theano/tensor/nnet/abstract_conv.py#L115).